# How to use Split View Controller with static Cells (many DetailsViewController)?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using a splitviewcontroller with a static cell. I wanted to know how to put several detailsViews and to display a specific detailview by pressing a cell of the table ?

[image]

Comment: From the looks of it you have a navigation controller as the root of the details.  Do you mean to change the controller on that navigation controller stack or to switch controllers entirely.

Comment: I only want to change the DetailViewController and always leave the TableView on the left (like the settings of an ipad).

Comment: There are lots of things that can effect how to do this.  I can provide a basic answer or if you can upload your project make it more specific to your usage.  Which would you prefer?

Comment: if you want you can create a project with only a SplitViewController with a static array and two or three DetailsViewController in Obj C.

Comment: Can you show how you are creating this 'static' array because there are several different ways I could do it.  It doesn't have to be complete just how you would set one up.

Comment: I will create a project with code and storyboard. I will send you the dropbox link. Then you'll just have to modify the DetailsViewController by pressing a specific cell.

Comment: Dropbox or a git repository should be fine.

Comment: try this link. It's ma project with 3 Viewcontrollers. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/bdq9smsha71nl1i/AAAZG1O1XHalwV6EyY9X5_yEa?dl=0

Comment: Well in that project the easiest way to do it is to go to the storyboard and right drag from the table view cell to the view controller you want and select a 'show detail' segue.  Do that for each of the cells and it should work fine.

Comment: oh yes it works very well. thank you very much.

Comment: Hello, you helped me a few days ago on a problem on xcode. I will need help on another problem. Would it be possible that we exchange by mail?

Comment: I don't usually give out my email address publicly.  What is the problem?

Comment: In fact, I would like to create an XML file and parse it. However, I do not know how to parse an XML file on xcode. If you wish I can create a project explaining what I want to better understand and send you the dropbox link ?

Comment: I think the best thing would be to create a new question about it, add some details (the dropbox link if you want) and then put a link to that new question here.  It's something I have done a few times so am sure I can help out.

Comment: OK. perfect. I prepare you this day and tonight I send you the links. thank you very much.

Comment: Ok no problem.  I'm working in the office tomorrow so might not be able to respond as quickly but I will take a look as soon as I can.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252007/parse-xml-fil-in-xcode-obj-c

Comment: Hello, I just updated the project. I have a mini question! I created a method to retrieve the values of the file but the values do not match. the method is in ViewController.m https://www.dropbox.com/sh/iiu23af1a1zbkwg/AACKChyoA6UTQXKrEyyxWJbxa?dl=0

Comment: Is this related to the other question not this one?

Comment: it's a new question

Comment: I just downloaded that project and it's v2 of your XML project with some errors.  Is that the correct one?  It doesn't build for a few reasons.

Comment: sorry. check this link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qsuhrobfzwpipl0/AABRj8JkNtpEjznD032XMKMRa?dl=0

Comment: My bad there was a bug in Airplane.m.  I have fixed it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6k036rtfwzrpk2/XML_project_tutorial_updated_v4.zip?dl=0

Comment: How to convert a NSDecimalNumber to float ?

Comment: NSDecimalNumber has a floatValue method so it's `[self.airplane.facteurBase floatValue]`

Comment: hello, I improved the storyboard by adding elements. The problem is that the labels and the image do not change when I modify the plane. can you help me ? thank you https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pxk4oxme406yril/AAAnPahd25wgdzpuFpQvClRQa?dl=0

Comment: In the first specs view the planeName is not linked and the ok button is not linked.  In the other spec views nothing is displayed because you only set the information for the initial specs view.  In order to pass the information you need to update them in the prepareForSegue method of the first specs view.  You would also be better off having separate view controllers rather than reusing specs view so much.

Comment: I have updated the example in your other question (check out the README for details)

Comment: Have you seen the latest version?

Comment: Yes. excuse me for the wait. I just modified for the OK buttons. However, I still can not display the image, the name of the plane and the description. I use Continer View.

Comment: Did you check out the README file?

Comment: yes. the problem is not in the XML file but it's just the display of my labels and my image in the view.

Comment: HINT: Check out the INFO at the end of the README file.  I will remove it fairly soon.

Comment: I just updated the project. but I can not display the name of the plane with the right image and description. Can you help me ? https://www.dropbox.com/sh/pxk4oxme406yril/AAAnPahd25wgdzpuFpQvClRQa?dl=0

Comment: Yes but you also need to read the last few lines of that README file.

Comment: You are using v4 of the project.  I updated to v5 which is on your other question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252007/how-to-parse-xml-file-in-objective-c.  You need to use that version as your v4 version has errors that have already been fixed in v5.  Plus v5 contains important info in the README file.

Comment: Hello,
I'm working on version 5. I'll let you know.

Comment: Good evening,
I just updated version 5. I updated the link. I have a problem with the OK button. Similarly, I wanted to know also how I do if I want to hide some planes in the picker view. I created a method with a button switch. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v1f1icdto3d34ps/AAC9LWyzgnUwNIiq-FPHTjY_a?dl=0

Comment: Ok I got the email so we can communicate via that instead of expanding the comments on this question.

Comment: Yes good idea ! thank you very much.