# How to put the same background on a SplitViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to know how I can do to put the same background on my SplitViewController (TableView and DetailVeiwController) ?

[image]

Comment: You appear to have a split view and tab bar controller.  Can you show a little of how you have set it all up as that will influence the solution

Comment: If you want an image to be used across the entire UISplitViewController you can try this: `splitViewController.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"TestImage"].CGImage);`

Comment: Your solution does not work. I put the code in ViewDidLoad but the background does not appear.

Comment: In what way didn't it work?  In which view controllers viewDidLoad did you put it?

Comment: I put it in ViewDidLoad of the UISplitViewController class file

Comment: Ok I have this `self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"TestImage"].CGImage);` in my viewDidLoad and it is working fine.  Have you also made sure that the backgrounds of both the master and details view controllers are set to be transparent and not some other colour and of course that the image is valid.

Comment: when I put this code, the Split View disappears, and only displays the DetailsView.

Comment: That's very strange behaviour.  Can you post the project for me to look at?

Comment: Excuse me I just have a try and finally it works. sorry.
Can you help me for another problem I have with my SplitViewController ?? look at this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050611/how-to-use-split-view-controller-with-static-cells-many-detailsviewcontroller

Comment: Ok I will take a look.  I'm going to put this as the answer for this question as it is working.  You don't need to accept it but it will show up for anyone else with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can put something like this in the viewDidLoad method of the UISplitViewController:

```
self.view.layer.contents = (__bridge id _Nullable)([UIImage imageNamed:@"TestImage"].CGImage);
```